# Swap content using a fade out/fade in effect HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was wondering if there is a way to swap the content of a html page with a nice fade in fade out effect using JS or jQuery.

In the HTML code I have below I cant to be able to swap out the section class="inner-wrapper" for some new content.

Would be great if you could help me out. :)

```
    <div class="meny">
 <a href="#">
  <section class="one-fourth" id="html">
   <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"><h3>Beställ</h3></i>
  </section>
 </a>
 <a href="#">
  <section class="one-fourth" id="social">
   <i class="fa fa-list-ul"><h3>Recept</h3></i>

  </section>
 </a>
</div>   
<!--övre delen slut-->
<!-- mitten-->
 <section class="inner-wrapper">
  <article id="one-two">
     <h2>Målet med vagnen</h2>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis repellat, distinctio alias expedita exercitationem maxime, dolores cumque rem beatae laudantium sint! Exercitationem perferendis, illum suscipit, cupiditate sit facere ullam harum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum aliquam explicabo beatae quam. Officia adipisci voluptatibus explicabo corrupti quaerat, non, voluptatem consequatur repellat in sequi. Odit adipisci dolore, deserunt labore!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt eaque deleniti debitis inventore unde aliquid nemo, optio ipsam voluptatum, a, libero laborum? Dolore eaque quod ratione optio voluptatum omnis reiciendis.</p>
  </article>
  <aside id="tablet2">
     <hr>
      <h2>Senaste nytt från vagnen</h2>
      <a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="500" data-height="600" href="https://twitter.com/ViktorParment">Tweets by ViktorParment</a> <script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </aside>
</section>
```

Edit:
sorry for the bad post :P

This is what I would like to swap it for when i CLICK on one of the one-fourth divs

```
    <a href="#">
<section class="one-fourth" id="html">
        <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"><h3>Beställ</h3></i>

</section>
</a>
<a href="#">
<section class="one-fourth" id="social">
    <i class="fa fa-list-ul"><h3>Recept</h3></i>

</section>
    </a>
</div>   
<!--övre delen slut-->
<!-- mitten-->
<section class="inner-wrapper2">
    <article id="one-two">
        <h2>Recept</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi sit quas quam accusamus, quia facilis illo omnis repudiandae distinctio architecto sed, deleniti ducimus mollitia sequi repellendus. Distinctio rerum maiores rem.</p>
    </article>
    <aside id="tablet2">
       <hr>
        <img src="img/pannkakor.jpg" alt="">

    </aside>
</section>
```

Comment: What javascript have you tired?

Comment: and please provide the "some ew content" you were saying

Answer (score 0):

You can use fadeOut and fadein for this. fadeout/fadeIn also provide a callback function which will be fired once action is completed.

Read here

http://api.jquery.com/fadein/
and
http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/

```js
$(".inner-wrapper").fadeOut( 3000, function() {
    $(this).html("<div>Hello</div>");
    $(".inner-wrapper").fadeIn(3000)
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="meny">
 <a href="#">
  <section class="one-fourth" id="html">
   <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"><h3>Beställ</h3></i>
  </section>
 </a>
 <a href="#">
  <section class="one-fourth" id="social">
   <i class="fa fa-list-ul"><h3>Recept</h3></i>

  </section>
 </a>
</div>   
<!--övre delen slut-->
<!-- mitten-->
 <section class="inner-wrapper">
  <article id="one-two">
     <h2>Målet med vagnen</h2>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis repellat, distinctio alias expedita exercitationem maxime, dolores cumque rem beatae laudantium sint! Exercitationem perferendis, illum suscipit, cupiditate sit facere ullam harum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum aliquam explicabo beatae quam. Officia adipisci voluptatibus explicabo corrupti quaerat, non, voluptatem consequatur repellat in sequi. Odit adipisci dolore, deserunt labore!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt eaque deleniti debitis inventore unde aliquid nemo, optio ipsam voluptatum, a, libero laborum? Dolore eaque quod ratione optio voluptatum omnis reiciendis.</p>
  </article>
  <aside id="tablet2">
     <hr>
      <h2>Senaste nytt från vagnen</h2>
      <a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="500" data-height="600" href="https://twitter.com/ViktorParment">Tweets by ViktorParment</a> <script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </aside>
</section>
```